# Class method from CommonJS module not accessible?

Tags: javascript, node.js, commonjs

I am working on a solution to the exercise "Tracking the Scalpel" from [Chapter 11 of the Eloquent Javascript book](http://eloquentjavascript.net/11_async.html#i_UvyahfUnfl). The book provides a CommonJS module for the code related to the chapter: [crow-tech.js](http://eloquentjavascript.net/code/crow-tech.js)

The following is my solution code so far:

```
const ct = require('./crow-tech');

function storage(nest, name) {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    nest.readStorage(name, result => resolve(result));
  });
}

async function locateScalpel(nest) {
    let place = await storage(nest, 'scalpel');
    if (place === nest.name) {
        return place;
    } else if (place !== null) {
        return await locateScalpel(place);
    } else {
        return null;
    }
}

function locateScalpel2(nest) {
  // Your code here.
}

locateScalpel(ct.bigOak).then(console.log);
// → Butcher Shop
```

Here `ct.bigOak` is an object of class `Node` which contains the method `readStorage`. In isolated testing with `console.log` I can see that `ct.bigOak` is correctly imported and that `ct.bigOak.readStorage` is a function. However, when I run the above code in Node I get this error message:

```
(node:5441) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: nest.readStorage is not a function
    at resolve (/home/<username>/programming/js/eloquent-javascript/tracking-the-scalpel.js:5:10)
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at storage (/home/<username>/programming/js/eloquent-javascript/tracking-the-scalpel.js:4:10)
    at locateScalpel (/home/<username>/programming/js/eloquent-javascript/tracking-the-scalpel.js:10:23)
    at locateScalpel (/home/<username>/programming/js/eloquent-javascript/tracking-the-scalpel.js:14:22)
(node:5441) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 2)
(node:5441) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

Is there some problem down the line of passing `ct.bigOak` into my local functions that is preventing the `readStorage` method from being recognized?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is with the second call to locateScalpel, not the first.

`locateScalpel(place)` - here.